# Set var based on switch

Tags: c#, switch-statement, var

I need to be able to change the type of an object based on a switch statement. The logic I would like to happen would be as follows:

```
    var orig;

    switch(ID)
    {
        case 1:
          orig = (List<ReportOne>)Session["Report"];
          break;

        case 2:
          orig = (List<ReportTwo>)Session["Report"];
          break;
    }


    var sort = from o in orig
               where o.ID == ReportID
               select o;

Session["SortedReport"] = sort.ToList();
```

But when I try this I get implicitly-type local variable must be initialized. Is there a way I can get this same functionality as the above logic.

Comment: what's the return type of your method?

Comment: Change 'var orig;' to 'object orig = null;' and it should work.

Comment: the method doesn't return anything but I need to set a session variable to the correct List<customType> after I run it through a linq statement

Comment: @Ironsides24 You're trying to return a value from here, so the method *must* return something, and here you're getting a value from the session, not setting the session.  You need to be much more specific about what you're doing with this object, as it affects how you can solve this problem.

Comment: I have added what I am doing with the object exactly

Comment: You should consider adding a common ancestor for your reports (interface with an ID property getter for instance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a parent interface to your reports:

```
IEnumerable<IReport> orig = Session["Report"] as IEnumerable<IReport>;
if (orig != null)
{
  var sort = from o in orig
             where o.ID == ReportID
             select o;

  Session["SortedReport"] = sort.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Cameron, this now has the original uninitialized problem if the ID isn't 1 or 2.

Comment: @Almo This is based on the assumption that the Id is declared prior to the block of code. The original question didn't specify where the Id was coming from. I would assume that it's passed in as a parameter.

Comment: @Cameron, the C# compiler would reject this block during compilation as if at runtime ID is not 1 or 2, orig would have an undefined value.

Comment: Is there any reason you cast just to store it back as an object?

Comment: Now that I have this my LINQ statement that uses orig now throws this error:

could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'object'

Comment: @Ironsides24 Do your reports inherit from the same base class?

Comment: They where implementing an interface but I am needing to get rid of the interface because that was causing other issues inside of the reports

Comment: @Ironsides24 It's quite likely you actually need a common ancestor in this case

Comment: @Ironsides24, you'll need at least an interface here. Not only for setting the `orig` variable, but for also accessing the `ID` property on items in the sequence. The compiler will not know about that property otherwise when you try to write your query.

Comment: That was the exact code I had before but once once you are using the sorted list report functionality(column sorting) wasn't working due to the column name not being in the interface. If I add all the column names to the interface then all report object will end up being the exact same which i cannot do

Comment: @Ironsides24, *at the very least*, you'll need an interface that defines the `ID` property if you want to use it in your query. Additional properties for the interface could be considered separately. Also remember that a class can implement multiple interfaces, so you do not need one interface to rule them all.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot Use Var for this. The compiler must know what type of object Var is.

What you can use is an interface, or base class.

If you assign an interface to both classes, or the same base class, you can replace

```
 var orig
```

with

```
 IEnumerable<baseClass> orig
```

Or

```
 IEnumerable<iClass> orig
```

If you need List functionality you can then convert IEnumerable.ToList() to achieve that functionality.

Comment: `List` is not covariant; it is not legal to use it in this manor.

Comment: @ChuckBuford You're assuming that the only thing that he'll ever do with these objects is iterate them.  What if that's not the case?  What if he actually needs to access `List` functionality?

Comment: @Servy Again, good point. Added the information for converting back to a list if needed.

Comment: I originally had this as above but that was giving an issue where every report object had to be identical

Comment: @Ironsides24 What do you mean by "had to be identical"?